# QOpenGLFramebufferObject toImage efficiency

Tags: qt, opengl, framebuffer

The toImage() method seems to be very slow in terms of real-time rendering. I render to the frame buffer using OpenGL but I need to then fetch the colour data back effeciently, is there a better way to do this than with a Qt fbo's toImage method? I do want to return a QImage.

Note: Using the toImage() function I get ~ 10fps when my target is at least 30fps. The buffer needs to hold RGBA data on a texture that is 1200*674 (so 1200*674*4 bytes are fetched)

Comment: were you ever able to improve on this? Got the same issue here.

Comment: @Dariusz No but there might be a way. I ended up not using Qt. You can however retrieve the image data with constBits(), you may be able to fill in an image or a pixmap faster with this

Comment: Hmm thats a bummer, I was looking over QT source code yesterday&today to see if I can find out how they retrieve the pixels from OpenGL and place in QImage (essentially how the toImage() function works) but All I found was a bunch of functions that just confused me like hell. Tricky! If I may how did you solve that in ur app then?

Comment: @Dariusz I can give you some tips, if you want increased efficiency with texture upload and download don't use Qt (especially older versions). Qt likes to hide useful OpenGL functions. Research 'pixel buffer objects' they can be used for increased efficiency when it comes to uploading and downloading texture data. You can infact use both OpenGL and Qt defined functions but you need to use 'wglGetProcAddress' (Windows) or 'glXGetProcAddress' (XWindows) and bind the functions you need yourself.

Comment: Awesome thanks for help and hints!

Comment: @Dariusz no problem, good luck